# How to display Object in array[]

Tags: javascript

I work on the same project and i'm again block. 
I will trying to explain my problem. 
Im working on a FAQ and i filter my answer. 
I write words in my input, that check if the word exists. If exists, He will push in an array the "panel". In the panel contain much data like the question and the answer of him. After the for when he finish, I have an array only with data who containes the word or the words.

Ok my question is : I trying to display, to convert my array for put my data in my site but i got a [object HTMLDivElement]. How can i exploit my array to show my data ? Thx

```
for (var j = 0; j < liSearchFaq.length; j++) {
    var panelClass = liSearchFaq[j].getElementsByClassName("panel");
        if (null != panelClass[0]) {
            panel = liSearchFaq[j].getElementsByClassName("panel")[0];
            searchIndex =  panel.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(word);

            if (searchIndex > -1) {
                array.push(panel);
                countFound++;
            }                                                                                       
        }        
    }                       
}


array.forEach(function(element) {
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = element[0];
    console.log(element);
});

console.log(array);
console.log(countFound);
```

Ok i show you screen shot for explain you what i try to do

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgsqt.png)
[Write Words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69rAU.png)

Ok in the first screen you see the array is empty and I havent problem like that
In the second screen you can see my push.panel on the array and how many panel I got in my array when I write a word. 
Actually in this example, i have 4 answer who have "Installation" in the answer or question
But did you see the undefined in top/right ? I trying to display the 4 data in my array

Comment: try to print element.innerHTML.

Comment: array.forEach(function(element) {
 element.innerHTML;
 console.log(element);
});

Like that ? My answers in default value, I put her on display none right ?
And with the element.innerHTML, change the value on display ?

Comment: this happens because you pushing html dome element to array and then try to stringify it.
Seems like you need to push smth else, not element itself
`array.push(panel);`

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean @SergiiVorobei. 
The problem is if I dont push "panel" in my array, I will dont display the answers and question. That's right ? Or i push ID and i recover with other  ?

Comment: then you probably need to push it's `innerText` or `innerHTML`
Or if you want to render smth from that, you should generate strings or DOM elements with other way, not with `JSON.stringify`,

Comment: @SergiiVorobei but finally, im wrong on the stringify, but how can i resolve the
[object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Could you please create a working example in the `jsfiddler` or `codepen`?
As it is not finally clear what are you going to achieve

Comment: I can't put in jsfiddle because i got all in local and variables are fat. But i can take screnshot for show you what its the problem